# how to Json Parsing and display data in Windwos Phone 7 using C# code

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

```
   void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);

            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/mobileservice.aspx?service=topstories"));
        }

   void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contacts>>(e.Result);         
        }

        public class Contacts
        {
            public string news_id { get; set; }
            public string news_title { get; set; }
            public string website_link { get; set; }
            public string imagepath { get; set; }
            public string news_date { get; set; }
            public string news_detail_description { get; set; }

        }
```

This is My C# code. I am able to count the Number of items  `var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contacts>>(e.Result);`  contain in response But i am Unable to Print data. Please help me how I can print. Please print atleast One item so that i can Understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prepare the UI in the XAML and set the databinding from the codebehind.

Example xaml code:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxNews" Margin="10,0,30,0" Height="486" Width="404" FontSize="20">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Margin="10,0,10,8">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding news_date}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding news_title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" /> 
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And databinding from codebehind.

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contacts>>(e.Result);
        ListBoxNews.ItemsSource = rootObject;
    }
```

Try this and ask me if you still have doubts.

Comment: thanx i m trying and will Get back to U